# Selenium element won't click

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem where `.click()` does not work on element. Once clicked with mouse it pops up a small window with values to choose from. However I can't make selenium click on that element as it gives me error, even if element is found. Using Selenium IDE and recording my actions it records click action on the same element so I do not understand what is not working. I navigated and clicked on a lot of elements up to this point.

Here is the code snippet that raises the error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

def FirefoxTest():
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/MYUSER/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/ethy92lt.default')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
    site = ("www.company_intranet.com")
    driver.get(site)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no-btn")))
    except:
        print("C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no-btn not found")
    driver.find_element_by_id("C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no-btn").click()
```

Element id I try to click:

```
<a class="th-ip-h" id="C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no-btn" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="thtmlb_hideContextMenu(event); thtmlbCSVHManger.inputfieldF4IconClick('C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no','C29_W35_V37_V46','ZSRQM_PROB_H','PROBLEMHEADEREF');htmlbSubmitLib('htmlb',this,'thtmlb:inputField:inputField:null','myFormId','C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no','\x23AUTONAV\x23OP_FINDRESPORG\x23BTRESPORG\x230\x23PARTNER_NO',0);return false;" onfocus="thtmlbSaveKeyboardFocus('C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no');thtmlb_hideContextMenu();" title="Open Input Help"><img class="th-ip-img" src="/SAP/BC/BSP/SAP/ZIR_STYLES/EHP3 default/images/helpF4.gif" alt="Open Input Help"></a>
```

Error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MYUSER/PycharmProjects/untitled/selen_QT.py", line 229, in <module>
    FirefoxTest()
  File "C:/Users/MYUSER/PycharmProjects/untitled/selen_QT.py", line 98, in FirefoxTest
    driver.find_element_by_id("C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no-btn").click()
  File "C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 75, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 454, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 102, in check_response
    value = json.loads(value_json)
  File "C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**Edit:** a sleep timer before have solved the issue

`time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no-btn").click()`

Comment: Just to clarify: The element you want to click one is in another window?

Comment: It's in the same window (source code). I fail to popup the another window to continue.

Comment: Did you try to inspect Firefox debugger to see if there's an error in there?

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with you `try` `except` block, you wait for the element but even if it times out you try to find it anyway. It should be as follows:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no-btn")))
    driver.find_element_by_id("C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no-btn").click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("C29_W35_V37_V46_btresporg_struct.partner_no-btn not found")
```

Although I don't think that's the root of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will adjust my Try blocks. As you mentioned, problem is not that i can't find element (I do and can print his ID), but that I get error when try clicking on it.

Comment: The problem seems to lie in the library. I look a bit in the known bugs of selenium and saw a similar one, I'm not 100% sure that's the same one though. It seems like the driver is trying to unpack a JSON message from Firefox API but failing to do so because it's actually empty. I'm afraid it's out of your hands.

Comment: I put 5 seconds timer before making the click and that made popup appear. I guess despite finding element, website needed some time to fully load or something. I need to do a bit more testing.